# A question regarding specific heat capacity

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation

If an object requires energy $E$ to change its temperature by $1K$ and I provide it a kinetic energy of magnitude $E$, does the temperature increases or does the temperature changes only when the energy provided is heat energy?

Comment: Hint: what does temperature measure?

Comment: Temperature, as the way I am taught, measures mean kinetic energies of the particles in a substance.

Comment: What does the full first law of thermodynamics tell you?

Comment: Increase in internal = heat supplied to system +work done on the system. Internal is the sum of kinetic energies and potential energies in the system. So if I provide kinetic energy, technically I would've increased internal energy and assuming no intermolecular forces are present, increasing internal would've increased the temperature. Is this correct?